# Empty spaces after load FBX to Spark AR

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to load a 3D model I made in Blender to Spark AR as FBX formatted file. After loading, some spaces of my model looks just empty. When I remove the material from Spark, the grey object itself also has that empty spaces.

The object in Blender is looking good. When I use DAE format, the object looks correctly, but the texture looks too saturated.

I attach the photo of incorrect FBX imported object so you can see what I mean. Do you have any thought why it's happening and how to fix this? Or maybe I should use DAE only?

[image]

Comment: Check if your model has some Ngons.

Comment: @LeoNas I checked and it had! Thank you a lot! I fixed everything following this article: http://iamlukeb.com/how-to-quickly-easily-convert-ngons-to-quads-tris-blender-3d/